# Creating multiple linked tables in Access with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb, linked-tables

So I currently have this code

```
Public Sub DoTrans()

   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

   dbPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\db1.accdb"
   dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
   dbWs = Application.ActiveSheet.Name

   scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & dbPath
   dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]" & "namedrange1"

   cn.Open scn
   ssql = "INSERT INTO Table1 ([fdName], [fdOne], [fdTwo]) "
   ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh

   cn.Execute ssql

End Sub
```

But this inserts into existing Access table. I'd like to be able to modify this to create linked tables, based on a list of named ranges that I have in Excel so that all the named ranges will be converted to tables in Access. Formatting is not an issue as I know the format of the ranges that are named are OK to be used as tables in Access.

Is there a way to easily do this?

Comment: Did you try TransferSpreadsheet method?

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT INTO` appends to existing tables, `SELECT .... INTO` creates new ones.

If you want to rewrite that query to a `SELECT INTO`, it would be as simple as this:

```
ssql = "SELECT * INTO Table1  "
ssql = ssql & "FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh
```

Note that you first need to delete the table if you want to overwrite it.

Your question has several subquestions. I can get into creating links in ADO on specific columns, but you haven't shown an attempt, nor have you shared enough information to write an applicable answer.

Answer (score 2):

A sample to elaborate on the TransferSpreadsheet method :

```
Dim sNT as String, sWB as String, sRN as String
  sNT = "Table1"
  sWB = "C:\MyWorkBook.xls"
  sRN = "namedrange1"
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet acLink, , sNT, sWB, True, sRN
```

This has to be run in a module in ms-access.

Comment: Good contribution, but try to fill in the blanks with all you can deduce from the example (e.g. `sNT = "Table1"`, since it's `Table1` in the example. Also note that you can run this from Excel using the `Access.Application` object (e.g. `Dim accApp As New Access.Application <br> accApp.OpenCurrentDb dbPath <br> accApp.DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet`). It will require a reference to the Microsoft Access xx.0 Object Library.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Iedited the post! And I indeed forgot about the accApp-trick ;-)